# Qiskit IBMQ.load_account fails on version 0.20.0

Tags: qiskit, programming

So when trying to load my account I get this error:

```
ibmqfactory._initialize_providers:WARNING:2020-08-16 17:47:17,410: Unable to instantiate provider for {'hub': 'ibm-q', 'group': 'open', 'project': 'main'}: "{'online_date': ['Not a valid datetime.']}"
ibmqfactory.load_account:WARNING:2020-08-16 17:47:17,411: No Hub/Group/Projects could be found for this account.
```

I have tried changing the date format on my machine but other than that I'm lost.

Comment: So it works for other versions but fails for 0.20.0? I wasn't the close voter, but I do worry that others will close this question if it looks like it lacks details.

Comment: @user1271772 the error does not appear on older versions

Comment: If you try to delete the saved credentials and re-save them, do you get this error? You can do this by running `IBMQ.delete_account()`, and then save them again by running `IBMQ.save_account(<token>)`. Then you can try loading them again.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like this issue: https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-ibmq-provider/issues/677

Can you verify the version of your qiskit elements by doing

```
import qiskit
print(qiskit.__qiskit_version__)
```